What is the translation of blanagram in French?
From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blanagram:

A blanagram ( portmanteau of blank and anagram ) is a word which is an anagram of another but for the substitution of a single letter. The term has its origin in competitive Scrabble, where a blank tile on a player's rack may be used to form any of several possible words in conjunction with the player's other tiles.

What is the translation of blanagram in French?

My findings:

Google Translate suggests "blanagramme" but I don't see being used. A French translation could be based on joker instead, for example.
larousse.fr doesn't have the term.
Linguee doesn't suggest any interesting translations.


There is no sensible reason not to translate blanagram as blanagramme.
A couple of web sites already do it:

Blanagramme
Un blanagramme est un mot qui est l'anagramme d'un autre, mais où une seule lettre est remplacée. Par exemple, pile devient lire. Dans un jeu de Scrabble, par exemple, un blanagramme est créé en ajoutant une lettre blanche là où c'est nécessaire pour démêler les lettres afin de former un anagramme.
motsCroises.fr


Blanagram
Résolvez des énigmes de mots difficiles en changeant une lettre à la fois. Allez au mot suivant en réorganisant les lettres comme des anagrammes, mais en remplaçant également une lettre. C'est un blanagramme.
fr.altapps.net


Thanks. Could've been based on joker instead, for example.
